# Salamalec - meaning

Tags: sens

I have heard the following in the TV series Marseille:

> J'en ai marre de tout ça. Les journalistes, les trucs officielles, les discours, les salamalecs avec des gens dont j'en n'ai rien à foutre. C'est lourd.

Context: The Marseille mayor is telling his wife that he's fed up with his everyday life as mayor.

What does "salamalec" mean? I could not find it in the Larousse and Word Reference dictionaries.

Comment: It is referenced in Larousse online (but in the plural form only): https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/salamalecs/70632

Comment: https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/salamalec. https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/salamalec. https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/salamalec. If you looked for *salamaleque* (cf. in your title) there's no chance you could find it in a French dictionary.

Comment: @None thanks for pointing out my mistake, I have indeed confused "salamalec" and "salamaleque". I have fixed the question title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Salamalecs* (most ofthen used in the plural) are exaggerated shows of politeness, eg when greeting or welcoming someone at a formal event. The word has a negative connotation, being used to stress how time-consuming, hypocritical or meaningless they can be.

See https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/salamalec